# MySQL upgrade 5.1 to 5.5

Tags: mysql

When I upgraded from MySQL 5.1 to 5.5 with the command

```
mysql_upgrade -S /var/run/mysqld/mysql.sock
```

I got this error:

```
magento.sales_flat_shipment
error: Table rebuild required. Please do "ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_shipment` FORCE "or dump reload to fix it!
```

Now I've looked again with the command

```
mysqlcheck --check-upgrade --all-databases -p -S /var/run/mysqld/mysql.sock
```

but the error is no longer displayed.

The error was also displayed on other tables. And even with the other tables, the error with `mysqlcheck` is no longer displayed.

**My question**:
Is the table really fixed, or should I still execute the SQL command:

```
ALTER TABLE `XYZ` FORCE"
```

Comment: What's the harm in doing the migration step anyways?

Comment: It the error fixed or not? - by using mysql_upgrade.

Comment: I dunno, but it can't hurt to re-do `ALTER TABLE xyz FORCE` again if you're concerned.

Comment: Not really :) If is not need - I'll not do this. (over 500 tables on ~150 databases)